# Call gnumake on all subdirs in parallel (-j) and only then run the linker-rule last (i.e. order important)

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, gnu-make

I have a c++ makefile project. It works great for non-parallel building. It works 99% for parallel building... the only problem I have is that I can't get my final executable link-line to run last (it must be the last thing that happens).

I have some constraints: I don't want to have any PHONY dependencies on my link line because this causes it to re-link every time. I.e. once my target is built, when I re-build it should not be re-linked.

Here is (slightly contrived) minimal example. Please don't try to pick holes in it, its really here just to show the problem, its not real, but the problem I am showing is. You should be able to just run this and see the same issue that I am.

```
# Set the default goal to build.
.DEFAULT_GOAL = build

#pretend subdirs (these don't really exist but it does not matter so long as they always try to be built)
MAKE_SUB_DIRS = 1 2 3

#pretend shared objects that are created by the pretend makefile sub directories (above)
OUTPUTS = out1.so out2.so out3.so

# Top level build goal - depends on all of the subdir makes and the target.out
.PHONY: build
build: $(MAKE_SUB_DIRS) target.out
    @echo build finished

# Takes 1 second to build each of these pretend sub make directories. PHONY so always runs
.PHONY: $(MAKE_SUB_DIRS)
$(MAKE_SUB_DIRS):
    @if [ ! -f out$@.so ] ; then echo making $@... ; sleep 1 ; echo a > out$@.so ; fi

# The main target, pretending that it needs out1,2 and 3 to link
# Should only run when target.out does not exist
# No PHONY deps allowed here
target.out:
    @echo linking $@...
    @ls $(OUTPUTS) > /dev/null
    @cat $(OUTPUTS) > target.out

# Clean for convinience
clean:
    @rm -rf *.so target.out
```

Now, I don't really care about `make` working, what I want is `make -j` to work. Here is me trying to run it:

> ```
> admin@osboxes:~/sandbox$ make clean 
> admin@osboxes:~/sandbox$ 
> admin@osboxes:~/sandbox$ make -j     - 1st attempt
> making 1...
> making 2...
> linking target.out...
> making 3...
> ls: cannot access 'out1.so': No such file or directory
> ls: cannot access 'out2.so': No such file or directory
> ls: cannot access 'out3.so': No such file or directory
> makefile:24: recipe for target 'target.out' failed
> make: *** [target.out] Error 2
> make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
> admin@osboxes:~/sandbox$ 
> admin@osboxes:~/sandbox$ make -j     - 2nd attempt
> linking target.out...
> build finished
> admin@osboxes:~/sandbox$ 
> admin@osboxes:~/sandbox$ make -j     - 3rd attempt
> build finished
> admin@osboxes:~/sandbox$
> ```

So I highlighted my three attempts to run it.

- Attempt 1: you can see all 4 dependencies of build are started at the same time (approx). Since each of the `makeing x...` take 1 second and the `linking` is nearly instant we see my error. However all the three "libraries" are build correctly.
- Attempt 2: The libraries only get created if they don't already exists (that's bash code - pretending to do what a makefile might have done). In this case they are already created. So the Linking passes now since it just requires the libraries to exist.
- Attempt 3: nothing happens because nothing needs to :)

So you can see all the steps are there, its simply a matter of ordering them. I would like the the make sub dirs `1, 2, 3` to build in any order in parallel and then only once they are all completed I want `target.out` to run (i.e. the linker).

I don't want to call it like this though: `$(MAKE) target.out` because in my real makefile I have lots of variables all setup...

I have tried looking at (from othe answers) `.NOT_PARALLEL` and using the dep order operator `|` (pipe), and I have tried order a load of rules to get target.out to be last.... but the `-j` option just ploughs through all of these and ruins my ordering :( ... there must be some simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: add an example of ways to pass variables to sub-makes. Optimized a bit by adding `$(SUBDIRS)` to the prerequisites of `build` instead of making them in its recipe.

I am not sure I fully understand your organization but one solution to deal with sub-directories is as follows. I assume, a bit like in your example, that building sub-directory `foo` produces `foo.o` in the top directory. I assume also that your top Makefile defines variables (`VAR1`, `VAR2`...) that  you want to pass to the sub-makes when building your sub-directories.

```
VAR1    := some-value
VAR2    := some-other-value
...
SUBDIRS := foo bar baz
SUBOBJS := $(patsubst %,%.o,$(SUBDIRS))

.PHONY: build clean $(SUBDIRS)

build: $(SUBDIRS)
    $(MAKE) top

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ VAR1=$(VAR1) VAR2=$(VAR2) ...

top: top.o $(SUBOBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

top.o: top.cc
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f top top.o $(SUBOBJS)
    for d in $(SUBDIRS); do $(MAKE) -C $$d clean; done
```

This is parallel safe and guarantees that the link will take place only after all sub-builds complete. Note that you can also `export` the variables you want to pass to sub-makes, instead of passing them on the command line:

```
VAR1    := some-value
VAR2    := some-other-value
...
export VAR1 VAR2 ...
```

Comment: So for me I have variables that have been passed into my makefile - so I think I need to pass these variables into the `$(MAKE) top` and `$(MAKE) $(SUBDIRS)` commands? - I know my example is a bit rubbish, its difficult to simulate the problem of my larger makefile system. Thanks : )

Comment: How do you define these variables? Command line? Environment variables? In the Makefile itself?

Comment: They are makefile variables  -  I have just found the `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES:` rule which seems to help here

Comment: Yes, you can use `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES`. Or [export](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Variables_002fRecursion) just the variables you want to pass to sub-makes. Or pass them (as shown in my edited answer) on the command line of the sub-make invocations.

Comment: Thanks very much... I really don't like the pass-by-command line version of var passing because (and this is where my troubles started a few weeks back) they override any attempt to change them in sub-make files (i.e. `VAR += another` would have no effect). So I am a big fan of exporting :)

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would just add the lib files as prerequisites of target.out:

```
target.out: $(OUTPUTS)
        @echo linking $@...
```

The thing is, this will relink target.out if any of the output lib files are newer.  Normally this is what you want (if the lib has changed, you need to relink target), but you specifically say you do not.

GNU make provides an extension called "order only prerequisites", which you put after a `|`:

```
target.out: | $(OUTPUTS)
        @echo linking $@...
```

now, target.out will only be relinked if it does not exist, but in that case, it will still wait until after `$(OUTPUTS)` have finished being built

If your `$(OUTPUT)` files are build by subsirectory makes, you may find you need a rule like:

```
.PHONY: $(OUTPUT)
$(OUTPUT):
        $(MAKE) -C $$(dirname $@) $@
```

to invoke the recursive make, unless you have other rules that will invoke make in the subdirectories

Comment: Thanks for that. I read that it is much simpler to order your makefile system/heirachy by just calling make on the sub dirs and not adding targets for each specific library - that is dealt with by their own makefile. Here I have to define rules how to build the `$(OUTPUTS)`? - that means I need to link the $(OUTPUTS) list to their subfolder so I can call make on them? Also the `|` does not have an effect in parallel builds....

Comment: @code_fodder: if you require calling Make recursively in the subdirs, you ought to say so in the Question.

Comment: @code_fodder: Generally you [DO NOT want to use recursive make](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) in subdirectories if you can at all avoid it.  Its much better to use `include` if you have a make (such as GNU make) that supports it.

Comment: @Beta I do not REQUIRE to recursivley call make. But each sub dir contains a seperate project in their own right - I don't know (or want to know) about their specifics. It just needs to be built and give me the output I need (e.g. a library) - how it does that is "its" problem...  If you have a better solution, please feel free to suggest : )

Comment: @ChrisDodd. So I got it all working more-or-less, but then I found that the libs either always link or never link. Then I came back to your answer and then it clicked what you are getting at.... I think you are suggesting similar to how c++ auto dep file are layed out, where they create dependencies on header files with rules to "build" these headers that are emtpy (becuase there is nothing we can do to generate a header if it is missing). So Your answer plus the line: `$(OUTPUTS):` (an empty rule) works for me here .. would you agree that approach?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have found "a" solution... but it goes a little bit against what I wanted and is therefore ugly (but not that *that* ugly):

The *only* way I can fathom to ensure order in parallel build (again from other answers I read) is like this:

```
rule: un ordered deps
rule:
    @echo this will happen last
```

Here the three deps will be made (or maked?) in any order and then finally the echo line will be run.

However the thing that I want to do is a rule and specifically so, such that it checks if anything has changed or if the file does not exist - and then, and only then, runs the rule.

The only way I know of to run a rule from within the bode of another rule is to recursively call make on it. However I get the following issues just calling make recursively on the same makefile:

1. Variables are not passed in by default
2. Many of the same rules will be re-defined (not allowed or wanted)

So I came up with this:

**makefile:**

```
# Set the default goal to build.
.DEFAULT_GOAL = build

#pretend subdirs (these don't really exist but it does not matter so long as they always try to be built)
MAKE_SUB_DIRS = 1 2 3

#pretend shared objects that are created by the pretend makefile sub directories (above)
OUTPUTS = out1.so out2.so out3.so

# Top level build goal - depends on all of the subdir makes and the target.out
export OUTPUTS
.PHONY: build
build: $(MAKE_SUB_DIRS)
    @$(MAKE) -f link.mk target.out --no-print-directory
    @echo build finished

# Takes 1 second to build each of these pretend sub make directories. PHONY so always runs
.PHONY: $(MAKE_SUB_DIRS)
$(MAKE_SUB_DIRS):
    @if [ ! -f out$@.so ] ; then echo making $@... ; sleep 1 ; echo a > out$@.so ; fi

# Clean for convinience
clean:
    @rm -rf *.so target.out
```

**link.mk:**

```
# The main target, pretending that it needs out1,2 and 3 to link
# Should only run when target.out does not exist
# No PHONY deps allowed here
target.out:
    @echo linking $@...
    @ls $(OUTPUTS) > /dev/null
    @cat $(OUTPUTS) > target.out
```

So here I put the linker rule into a separate makefile called link.mk, this avoids recursive make calling on the same file (and therefore with re-defined rules). But I have to export all the variables I need to pass through... which is ugly and adds a bit of a maintenance overhead if those variables change.

... but... it works :)

I will not mark this any time soon, because I am hopeful some genius will point out a neater/better way to do this...